# replace vowels with the character following it

Tags: java, string, replace

I'm trying to write a Java program in which it takes an input and replaces all the vowels with the character following it.

For example:

```
starcraft --> strrcrfft
parker --> prrkrr
```

This is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vowelconverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your string here: ");
        String myString = myInput.nextLine();
        String test = "";
        char vowels [] = {'a','e','i','o','u'};

        for (int i = 0; i <= myString.length(); i++){
            if (myString.charAt(i) == vowels[0] || myString.charAt(i) == vowels[1] || myString.charAt(i) == vowels[2] || myString.charAt(i) == vowels[3] || myString.charAt(i) == vowels[4]){       
                test = test + myString.charAt(i+1);
            }   
        }


        System.out.println(myString);
        System.out.println(test);
    }

}
```

Comment: What should be done in case of two consecutive vowels. Like `foobar`? What should be done with the consecutive `o`'s?

Comment: Furthermore, what if the last letter is a vowel, like: `hello`. What should one do with the last `o`?

Comment: In the case of consecutive vowels, it would just be replaced by the character after it. Such foobar would be fobbrr.

Comment: If the last letter is a vowel, I believe it should do nothing, since there is no character that comes after it.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically the kind of task where regular expressions are helpful. Here is a basic one that solves your problem:

```
s/[aeiouy]([^aeiouy])/$1$1/g
```

Answer (score 1):

MrFred's answer is a good one, but only works on vowels followed by non-vowels.  The more general (java) answer is

```
   myString = myString.replaceAll("[aeiouy](.)","$1$1" );
```

Do learn regex, it's extremely powerful.  The statement above is an extremely terse way of saying:

1. A match consists of a single character from this range (of vowels), followed by a subexpression comprising any single character.
2. Replace every match with two instances of the first subexpression ($1) from the match.

Answer (score 0):

- Use descriptive identifiers, like `inputString` and `outputString`; things like `myString` and `test` are unacceptable.
- Use a `String` for your vowels instead of a `char[]`, so that you can do `vowels.indexOf( character ) != -1` to check if the character is a vowel, instead of that loooooong `if` statement.
- Do not loop until the very end of the string; loop until `myString.length() - 1`, otherwise `myString.charAt(i+1);` will attempt to access a character beyond the end of the string.  After the loop is done, add the last character of the input string to the output string without checking if it is a vowel, because even if it is, there is nothing you can replace it with.
- To solve your main problem, (not building the output string properly,) consider this: on each iteration of the loop, you must be appending a character to the output string.  You cannot be only appending a character under certain conditions, because if you do that, then some characters from the input string will never make it to the output string.

Comment: What i was trying to do with test = test + myString.charAt(i+1) was attempting to store the char at the next index of the string to where the vowel originally was. Thanks for your advice!